# Utilizing wkhtmltopdf in PHP without exec permissions

Tags: php, exec, wkhtmltopdf

Anyone know if is it possible to use the html to pdf conversion tool named wkhtmltopdf on a server that doesn't have the possibility to use the exec commands or edit the php.ini.

Something like a library to include?

Comment: @stereofrog: but using that you have to compile it then edit the php.ini (as I said I don't have permissions to edit it).

Comment: Don't tell it to me! Tell it to my customers that don't want to change their server ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't execute binaries or edit the php.ini, you can't load an extension either. What you're asking for simply isn't possible.

Comment: I thought the same, but I hope someone could find some kind of solutions. Thanks anyway :)